# run liquibase from springboot inside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, liquibase

I run a spring boot application inside eclipse:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StatBasketServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StatBasketServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

 spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

When the application starts, no liquibase change is done.

Do i need to do something inside the gradle build? If i look at the console I don't see anything about liquibase.

The changelog is inside

> resouces/db/changelog.xml

## Update

That's my build file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'statBasketServer'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
} 


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")    
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-solr")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas")
    compile("org.json:json:20141113")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc4")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.6.1")
    compile("org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1")
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.4.1211.jre7'        
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
    testCompile("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.8.1") 

}
```

Comment: I think you can clarify more, we cant see the changelog if you mention it there like that.

Comment: But it's not a problem of changeset, the same changeset runs in other applications, it's a starting problem. When springboot starts no liquibase message is displayed in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need add `org.liquibase:liquibase-core` to your classpath
2. By default it will read `db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml` as the default changelog, or you can config it via `liquibase.change-log` in `application.properties`, spring boot also support the xml, json liquibase scripts.

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-liquibase) is an example provided by spring boot, you can refer to it, one point is this example is using maven as the build tool.

Comment: the first point: i think it'allready include with the gradle dependencies, or not?

Comment: @mautrok maybe you need config it yourself,

Comment: Huang yes i've read it to have a help, but the buil is in maven, and i have gradle. I'll try to see if liquibase is not in the classpath

Comment: It is eaiser to add it `compile('org.liquibase:liquibase-core')`

Comment: yes sorry in the moment that i write the build i have immediatly seen my mistake, still i don't know if it work i'm trying